# How to use a type definition in another file with swaggo?

Tags: go, package, include, swagger, godoc

I am using [swaggo](https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger) generate API document based on `godoc` syntax.

Source folder and files

```
|-post
|--controller.go
|--response.go
```

For this definition:

```
controller.go

package post

...

// Index godoc
// @Summary Index Post
// @Success 200 {array} []*Response
// @Router /v1/posts [get]
func Index(ctx *gin.Context) {
  ...
}
```

The `Response` is been defined in an another file but the same package.

```
response.go

package post

// Response  is post response body
type Response struct {
    ID   int64  `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`

    CreatedAt string `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt string `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

But when run `swag init` to generate swagger docs, it said:

```
2021/01/29 09:39:56 Generate swagger docs....
2021/01/29 09:39:56 Generate general API Info, search dir:./
2021/01/29 09:39:56 ParseComment error in file application/post/controller.go :cannot find type definition:
```

When I move the `Response` struct to `controller.go`, it works.

How to import it with godoc or swaggo?

Answer (score 13):

I also encountered this problem, but I solved it with the below command:

```
swag init --parseDependency --parseInternal
```

Comment: I tried this for echo, and is working fine

Answer (score 7):

You need to append `--parseDependency` to the `swag init` command.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick solution, run

```bash
go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@v1.6.7
```

You can find more about this solution [here](https://github.com/swaggo/swag/issues/817).

Answer (score 0):

`swag init --parseDependency true` should solve your issue